# How to fake an object in NSubstitute and ignore its method's internal implementation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I'm new to NSubstitute and trying to fake an existing class named `OrgDataWS`. This class has a method named `GetDataSet`:

```
 public XmlElement GetDataSet(int token)
 {
        string perfLogMessage = string.Format("Org.GetDataSet: {0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        MultiMessagePerformanceCounter performanceCounter = MultiMessagePerformanceCounter.StartNew(perfLogMessage);
        XmlElement result = orgDataManager.GetDataSet(token);
        performanceCounter.Stop();

        return result;
 }
```

The following is my test methods:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void GetDataSetTest()
 {
      var dataWSStub = Substitute.For<OrgDataWS>();

      var orgManagerStub = Substitute.For<OrgDataManager>();

      var document = new XmlDocument();
      var xmlElement = document.CreateElement("a");
      orgManagerStub.GetDataSet(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns<XmlElement>(xmlElement);


      dataWSStub.OrgDataManager = orgManagerStub;


      var result = dataWSStub.GetDataSet(99);
 }
```

However, when I run my test methods, this line

```
orgManagerStub.GetDataSet(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns<XmlElement>(xmlElement);
```

threw an exception. This exception is from the implementation of `OrgDataManager` class, from my understanding, this is not supposed to happen. The purpose of using that clause is that I hope if the `orgManagerStub`'s `DataDataSet` method is invoked with any `Int` parameter, just return my `xmlElement` instance. I didn't hope my code to run the detailed implementation of `OrgDataManager`.

What's wrong with my test code? How to fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can substitute concrete types, at the very least the method needs to be virtual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/):

> Warning: Substituting for classes can have some nasty side-effects. **For starters, NSubstitute can only work with virtual members of the class**, so any non-virtual code in the class will actually execute! If you try to substitute for your class that formats your hard drive in the constructor or in a non-virtual property setter then you’re asking for trouble. If possible, stick to substituting interfaces.

*(my emphasis)*

The declaration you showed is not virtual, so the solution is to either create an interface for it, and substitute for that, or at least make that method virtual (and possibly other methods as well).

Comment: I understand your point. Actually I do have an interface for the class. However, from my point of view, I'm trying to test the implementation, or I want to make sure that the "orgDataManager"'s DataDataSet method was invoked. However, I can't define a property in the interface, which means i can't tell the object mocked from the interface to return my pre-defined XmlElement instance when it's "orgDataManager" object's GetDataSet method is invoked.

Comment: Well, i see how to test. I need to test the manager, not the OrgDataWS.

Comment: The important part here is **substitute**, unless you give NSubstitute a method to do the substitution, it can't do its job.